# Does redis template have a query language?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

Does redis template have a query language?. Let's assume that I have in the redis cache a list stored as so:
key     value
mylist    ->  [1,2,3,4,5]

And I want to get the values in the list that match a certain criteria. Can we do this with the redis template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use redis command 'sort' to fill in the requirement. you can ref [here](https://redis.io/commands/sort). In spring, you use SortQueryBuilder to map this command. myList is a key stored [1,2,3,4,5] in redis.

1. define a redisTemplate bean

```java
    
    @Bean(name="myRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate myRedisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();

        template.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
        template.setValueSerializer(stringRedisSerializer);

        return template;
    }
```

2. In a service class autowired this bean

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.query.SortQuery;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.query.SortQueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.SortParameters;

@Service
public class MyService{

       @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate myRedisTemplate;

      public void find(){

        // >=3
        SortQuery<String> sortQuery = SortQueryBuilder.sort("myList").order(SortParameters.Order.ASC).limit(2,-1).build();
        List<String> sortRslt = myRedisTemplate.sort(sortQuery);
        for(String s : sortRslt) {
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        // >3
        sortQuery = SortQueryBuilder.sort("myList").order(SortParameters.Order.ASC).limit(3,-1).build();
        sortRslt = myRedisTemplate.sort(sortQuery);
        for(String s : sortRslt) {
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        // >2 && < 5
        sortQuery = SortQueryBuilder.sort("myList").order(SortParameters.Order.ASC).limit(2,2).build();
        sortRslt = myRedisTemplate.sort(sortQuery);
        for(String s : sortRslt) {
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

If query string, you should change data type from list to set. then use 'sscan' command with match pattern param to do it.

For instance, there are {'abc', 'hello', 'follow', 'five', 'beijing'} in a set named mySet. and you want to find string start with f.

```java
        ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match("f*").count(1).build();
        try (Cursor<String> cursor = myRedisTemplate.boundSetOps("mySet").scan(options)){
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                String value = cursor.next();
                System.out.println("value is " + value);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
        }
```

Comment: That's good when you have numbers. What if you have strings in the list and you are trying to map a certain value?

Comment: I think if I use the rediscallback, whatever code I put there will be executed in redis and not in my program right?

Comment: I comment something in answer. No matter redisTemplate or redisCallback, you had better to use redis command to query. The program code just invoke redis command as if executed in redis-cli